# BigQuery how to print string even if row is null

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to print a string answer to a question, on whether a specific item was bought today. I want the end result to look something like this:

```
| was_the_item_bought  | 
| -------------------- | 
| "no one bought this" |
```

However I keep getting null / no rows displayed.

```
| was_the_item_bought  | 
| -------------------- |
```

Here's the simplified query.

```
#StandardSQL

with store_list AS (
select item 
from store
),

bought_today AS (
select item 
from register 
where item = 'apple' # <--- only one item will be listed here
)

select (case when b.item is NULL 
    then "no one bought this" 
    else "bought" end) as was_the_item_bought
from store_list a  
left join bought_today b  
on a.item = b.item
```

How can i make it display a string?

Edit: Updated to specify it's `b.item` instead of `item`.

Comment: in your case clause, which item are you referring to? a.item, b.item? didn't you get any error for that?

Comment: @elyor updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out after a nap. I feel stupid.

```
#StandardSQL

with store_list AS (
select item 
from store
),

bought_today AS (
select item 
from register 
where item = 'apple' # <--- only one item will be listed here
)

select b.item, 
(case when b.item = a.item
    then "no one bought this" 
    else "bought" end) as was_the_item_bought
from store_list a  
right join bought_today b  
on a.item = b.item
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised you're not getting the error "Column name item is ambiguous at []" as your case statement doesn't reference which 'item' should be used?

The following query works fine. Is there anything in your 'store' table?

```
WITH store_list AS(
SELECT 'apple' item
UNION ALL
SELECT 'pear'),

bought_today AS (
SELECT 'orange' item
)

select (case when a.item is NULL 
then "no one bought this" 
else "bought" end) as was_the_item_bought
from bought_today b  
left join store_list a  
on a.item = b.item
```

Comment: there's definitely items in the store table. your query doesn't work the way I want - I don't want to show all items, only the 1 item being checked in bought_table table. when i use `b.item` instead of `a.item`, the row disappears when no quantities of that item is bought.

Comment: The join needs to be the other way round. Edit: Just seen you answered it

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a correlated join:

```
#StandardSQL

with store_list AS (
SELECT * FROM UNNEST(['apple','banana']) product
),

bought_today AS (
select * FROM UNNEST(['banana','banana','banana']) product
)

select product
  , (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bought_today b where a.product=b.product) bought_today
from store_list a
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but it's not doing what I want to do - don't want to count all items of each type that were bought. I want to print a statement whether an item was bought or not. But thanks!